# Nextjs Image component and setting width and height with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using the Image component that ships with Next.js but its forcing me to set the width and height as values. I am using Tailwind CSS and using their utility classes to set the height and width.

[image]

```
<Image
      src={imageSrc}
      alt={name}
      className="object-cover object-center"
      layout="fill"
/>
```

The HTML Css Code that works is

[image]

```
<img
    className="w-auto h-6 lg:block"
    src="/img/logo-dark.png"
    alt="nftHODL.club Logo"
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a wrapper div with the size and `relative` classes and then setting `layout="fill"` on the Image component should do the trick.

Example:

```
<div className="h-64 w-96 relative"> // "relative" is required; adjust sizes to your liking
  <Image
    src={img.img}
    alt="Picture of the author"
    layout="fill" // required
    objectFit="cover" // change to suit your needs
    className="rounded-full" // just an example
  />
</div>
```

Source: https://techinplanet.com/how-to-use-tailwind-css-with-next-js-image/

Answer (score 1):

If the image is not loaded from the web source (hence its size is known at the time of creating a bundle) it's simpler to do this:

```
import YourImage from '../your/assets/image.png'
import styles from '../your/image.module.css'

<Image
  src={YourImage}
  alt='This is an image'
  className={styles.image}
/>
```

and specify the size and other properties in the CSS file.